# Автоматизация настроки ipV6 с помощью скрипта на Mac OS X 10.8.*

Tags: bash, macos, mac

Здравствуйте!

Стало очень интересно автоматизировать настройку ipv6 через туннельного брокера на Mac OS X 10.8.4 
Может я пошел по сложному пути, но вот чтобы настроить его, нужно выполнить следующее

```
sudo ifconfig gif0 createsudo ifconfig gif0 tunnel YOU_IP_V4 216.66.84.46sudo ifconfig gif0 inet6 2001:470:1f14:32a::2 2001:470:1f14:32a::1 prefixlen 128sudo route -n add -inet6 default 2001:470:1f14:32a::1
```

Хотелось бы написать скрипт, который сотворить вот это, скрипты никогда не писал. Попытался решать проблему гуглением, но максимум что смог: открыть в браузере URL  и получить  IP  :)

Подсобите, кто чем может.

Comment: YOU_IP_V4  это что такое ? у вас динамический IP или вы за NAT ?

Comment: у меня белый IP, тут имеется ввиду IP машины, на которой нужно это выполнить

Answer (score 1):

читайте здесь http://tech.inhelsinki.nl/locationchanger/

в ~/bin/locationchanger

напишите:

```
#!/bin/shipv4b=YOUR_IPipv4a=216.66.84.46ipv6b=2001:470:1f14:32a::2 ipv6a=2001:470:1f14:32a::1ifconfig gif0 tunnel $ipv4b $ipv4aifconfig gif0 inet6 $ipv6b $ipv6a prefixlen /128route -n add -inet6 default $ipv6a
```

насчет create я не уверен, я прочитал это в доке вашего провайдера тонеля:http://www.tunnelbroker.net/forums/index.php?topic=19.0